# where for querying an array attribute in rails model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a user model with an array of roles.

```
u=User.first
u.roles = ['admin']
v=User.last
u.roles = ['admin', 'member']
```

How do i query to fetch all users with admin role?

Edit:
`roles` is a serialized array for the user model

*`User` Model:*

```
serialize :roles
```

*Migration:*

```
add_column :users, :roles, :string, default: []
```

Comment: What is `roles`? A serialize array? A `has_and_belongs_to_many` association?

Comment: Or is `roles` a PostgreSQL array column?

Comment: roles is a serialized array. Ve updated my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what "roles" means:

If it is an association as in

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
end
```

Then you look up the role and fetch all users:

```
Role.find_by_name("admin").users
```

or roles is just a column and it is serialised, in which case you can instantiate all users (slow)

```
User.all.select { |u| u.roles.include? "admin" }
```

Or query the database directly which is more complex and depends on the adapter.

My opinion: I would avoid using serialised columns, when relations can do. They are cumbersome in every way: Forms, Searches, Selects...

Comment: User.all.select { |u| u.roles.include? "admin" } does the trick. :) Thanks

Comment: could you up ote the answer to help others finding it faster? Thx

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using scopes:

### Model user.rb:

```
class User    
  scope :admins, -> () { where("roles @> ?", '{admin}')}
  scope :by_roles, -> (roles) { where("roles @> ?", "{#{roles.join(', ')}}") }
end
```

### Scoped calls, with results

Admins:

```
3.0.0 :001 > User.admins
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (roles @> '{admin}') /* loading for inspect */ LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 1, account_uuid: "0812df2d-58ed-4231-aca5-ec7708a156bb", email: "admin@example.com", password_digest: [FILTERED], first_name: "Admin", last_name: "Admin" remember_token: nil, remember_token_expires_at: nil, roles: ["user", "admin"], created_at: "2021-12-02 11:51:50.684788000 +0000", updated_at: "2021-12-02 11:51:50.684788000 +0000">]>
```

Users by_roles within single role:

```
3.0.0 :002 > User.by_roles(['user'])
User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (roles @> '{user}') /* loading for inspect */ LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 1, account_uuid: "0812df2d-58ed-4231-aca5-ec7708a156bb", email: "admin@example.com", password_digest: [FILTERED], first_name: "Admin", last_name: "Admin", remember_token: nil, remember_token_expires_at: nil, roles: ["user", "admin"], created_at: "2021-12-02 11:51:50.684788000 +0000", updated_at: "2021-12-02 11:51:50.684788000 +0000">, #<User id: 2, account_uuid: "7a09830d-bfde-45eb-abeb-4b305a7bb374", email: "user_1@example.com", password_digest: [FILTERED], first_name: "User", last_name: "Adviseman", remember_token: nil, remember_token_expires_at: nil, roles: ["user"], created_at: "2021-12-02 17:40:12.172547000 +0000", updated_at: "2021-12-02 17:40:12.172547000 +0000">, #<User id: 3, account_uuid: "a0044954-6ad0-4d8f-9681-bd5dfcfa72b7", email: "user_2@example.com", password_digest: [FILTERED], first_name: "User", last_name: "Adviseman", remember_token: nil, remember_token_expires_at: nil, roles: ["user"], created_at: "2021-12-02 17:40:12.583594000 +0000", updated_at: "2021-12-02 17:40:12.583594000 +0000">, #<User id: 4, account_uuid: "7d26e5d5-beaf-48bd-ad98-f53044a7182b", email: "user_3@example.com", password_digest: [FILTERED], first_name: "User", last_name: "Adviseman", remember_token: nil, remember_token_expires_at: nil, roles: ["user"], created_at: "2021-12-02 17:40:12.847412000 +0000", updated_at: "2021-12-02 17:40:12.847412000 +0000">]>
```

Users by_roles within multiple roles:

```
3.0.0 :003 > User.by_roles(['user', 'admin'])
User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (roles @> '{user, admin}') /* loading for inspect */ LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 1, account_uuid: "0812df2d-58ed-4231-aca5-ec7708a156bb", email: "admin@example.com", password_digest: [FILTERED], first_name: "Admin", last_name: "Bezugliy", remember_token: nil, remember_token_expires_at: nil, roles: ["user", "admin"], created_at: "2021-12-02 11:51:50.684788000 +0000", updated_at: "2021-12-02 11:51:50.684788000 +0000">]>
```